# Cocos2d update leaking memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

I have a weird issue - my app is leaking memory on device only, not on a simulator. It is leaking if i schedule update method anywhere, on any scene. It is leaking despite update method is empty, there's nothing inside it except NSLog. How can it be? I have even scheduled update on the very first scene where it seems there's nothing to leak, and scheduled another empty and it's leaking or not leaking but allocating something, the result is the same - the volume of the memory consumed is increasing and my app is crashing soon. 
I can detect the leakage via using Instruments->Memory->Activity Monitor or with help of following function:

```
void report_memory(void) 
{
struct task_basic_info info;
mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                               TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                               (task_info_t)&info,
                               &size);
if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) 
{
    NSLog(@"Memory in use (in bytes): %u", info.resident_size);
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Error with task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr));
}
}
```

Can anyone explain me what's going on?

Comment: The mach tools are not reliable tools to check for memory leaks. Does Instruments say that there's a leaked object? If so, it'll give you pointers to identify the leak. I'm guessing that you're mistaking an increase in memory for a memory leak. For a better answer please post the actual code where the leak is supposed to occur.

Comment: LearnCocos2d - first of all - i wanna thank you for the answer. As for the actual code it's really difficult to post something because it looks like - (void)update:(ccTime)delta{}. and that's all. it's enough to start leaking (or increasing memory, that's not really important). it may be not update: but any other scheduled method (empty!!!). It doesn't demand anything else, i take the very first scene, remove everything from there, all the code except scheduling update and the consumed memory starts growing. i see it both by using method adduced above and Instruments. this is what going on